# Socket.io is not working on live server but it works on localhost

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I installed Vynchronize (https://github.com/kyle8998/Vynchronize) yesterday and it worked perfectly on my localhost. The problem is that I want to upload it on a live server and as soon as do it, it seems that the following path https://mydomain.fr/socket.io/socket.io.js does not return the socket.io.js file so the website returns in the console this error : GET https://mydomain.fr/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_ABORTED 500

I'm really new to socket.io so I don't know what's happening, can you please help me ? :)

Comment: The socket.io server is hooked into your web server and should be serving `/socket.io/socket.io.js` for you automatically (as it does when run on localhost).  I would guess that something in the infrastructure for your live server (perhaps a proxy) is blocking it and giving the 500 status.  Is your live server configured to allow socket.io or webSockets?  What hosting platform are you using?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! I'm using OVH. I didn't know i had to configure my server. Do you have any ressource (video or tutorial) that shows how to do it please?

Comment: Which exact OVH plan?

Comment: It's the pro plan

Comment: Sorry, but "pro plan" does not tell me which type of hosting service you have.  Can you post a link to exactly what you have?  On their site, I see a bunch of different dedicated server plans, I see a bunch of different VPS plans, I see cloud services.  I'm trying to figure out exactly what you have.  Otherwise, I can't help because it's likely a configuration issue for your particular type of hosting.  Some types of VPS plans at some services don't even allow websockets/socket.io.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that the services in France and in the other part of the world are totally different. This is the link of my hosting service : https://www.ovh.com/fr/hebergement-web/hebergement-pro.xml . You'll find all the details about my hosting service. Thanks again for your help !! I'm trying to find solutions in different forum but so far I still find nothing.

Comment: I can't productively read the French site.  You will have to find out if your account allows webSocket or socket.io connections and, if so, what you have to configure to make it work.

Comment: Okay I understand, thank you for your help though :)